# Updating Multiple Instances of record Automatically

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I have an Excel spreadsheet with two columns: "Player" and "Price." There are multiple instances of each player. I tried a VBA code solution that automatically updates all other instances of a player's price when I change it for one instance. For example, if I change the price of one "Messi" to 3000, all other instances of "Messi" should update to 3000 without having to run the code every time. The problem is when I run the code nothing happens, I don't understand if there's a problem with the code itself or not. Appreciate any Help. Thanks.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' Define the range to watch (Column B)
Dim rngWatch As Range
Set rngWatch = Me.Range("B:B")

' Check if the changed cell is in the watched range
If Not Intersect(Target, rngWatch) Is Nothing Then
    ' Turn off events to avoid triggering the change event recursively
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim iValue As Variant
    Dim sKey As Variant
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim foundCell As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    
    ' Loop through the cells in the changed range
    For Each cell In Intersect(Target, rngWatch)
        ' Get the changed value in Column B and the corresponding value in Column A
        iValue = cell.Value
        sKey = Me.Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value
        
        ' Search through Column A for sKey and update the corresponding cells in Column B with iValue
        Set searchRange = Me.Range("A:A")
        Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(What:=sKey, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        
        If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
            Do
                foundCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = iValue
                Set foundCell = searchRange.FindNext(foundCell)
            Loop While Not foundCell Is Nothing And foundCell.Row <> cell.Row
        End If
    Next cell
    
    ' Turn events back on after all changes are made
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

The data would look like this:

| Player | Price |
| --- | --- |
| Messi | 5000 |
| Ronaldo | 950 |
| Zlatan | 600 |
| Salah | 700 |
| Xavi | 400 |
| Salah | 700 |
| Xavi | 400 |
| Messi | 5000 |

Comment: Is there a reason not to use VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH formulas?

Comment: it works but it has some limitations.  the issue is that I would have to create new column for the modified prices and if I updated any instance other than the first one of the player it doesn't reflect in the modified prices. for ex: if I changed the last "Messi" to 10000 the price in the modified price column would still be 5000.

Comment: This code works fine for me.  I suspect that your `Application.EnableEvents` might be set to `False`.  Open the debug window and type `Application.EnableEvents = True` and press Enter to verify that it's on.  Then, see if your code runs.

Comment: Always a good idea to add an error handler which ensures that events aren't left disabled if your code has a problem.

Comment: @TehDrunkSailor Done that. code is still working and not giving error either. Still don't know what is the issue.

Comment: @TimWilliams Tried that also without success.

Comment: @sherbman Does the `Worksheet_Change` fire when you make a change to a cell?  If you run through your code line-by-line, does it go through the `Do` loop?

Comment: That code works fine for me.

Comment: @TehDrunkSailor For some reason I can't run through my code with F8. It just gives error sound.

Comment: You can't run an event sub with a parameter using F8 - you need to put a breakpoint, then trigger it from the worksheet to be able to step through using F8.